# How can i chagne the ctcallstate to connected?

Tags: ios, core-telephony

i am going through CTCallState handling, i was wondering if i can change the call state from incoming to connected?
i am using this code below?

```
CTCallCenter *callCenter = [[CTCallCenter alloc] init];
    callCenter.callEventHandler=^(CTCall* call){
        if (call.callState == CTCallStateIncoming)
        {
            call.callState == CTCallStateConnected;
        }
    };
```

Comment: callState: The state of the cellular call. `(read-only)`

Comment: is there any other way to accept the call ?

Comment: that's messing with the phone outside the sandbox and Apple won't allow anything like that onto the store.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the state of the call from your app since the property is **readonly**.

```
@property(nonatomic, readonly, copy) NSString *callState  __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_NA,__IPHONE_4_0);
```